# What is the fastest way of installing Ubuntu? (Can you install without a cd or dvd?)

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, iso, burning

Is it possible to install an iso file without burning it to a CD/DVD/USB and run it in some type of software instead? I am just curious if there is a faster way to install an iso file.

Comment: When you say install, do you mean mount the image file so that you can access it's contents? If so, you can indeed. There are instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountIso) which cover doing this from the CLI as well as from the GUI. Tom

Comment: What are you trying to install?  Are you trying to install from Linux or Windows?

Comment: I went to mount vivid-desktop-i386.iso and gISOMount said it was not an iso file. Yet it has a .iso extension?  (It's the Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop Image)

Comment: I would assume the ISO is not downloaded correctly. did you check the checksum of the download?

Comment: The MD5 is e0ff0a3fd9c704bbd84ab4170c9d3d54

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fast SLC USB key on a USB 3.0 port is the *fastest* way of installing a *single* machine...

If you're deploying to multiple *different* machines, PXE boot is the fastest way.

If you're deploying to multiple *identical* machines, CloneZila Server is the fastest way.

Comment: What is "A fast SLC USB key on a USB 3.0 port is the fastest way of installing a single machine.."? May I have a little bit more information on that

Comment: There are two kinds of USB keys: Cheap and expensive.  The cheap ones use MLC (=Multi-Level Cell) storage.  That is: they store more then one bit in 1 cell of the chip.  The expensive ones use SLC (Single-Level Cell) storage: they only store 1 bit in one cell.  The SLC USB keys are a 8 times as fast and 8 times as reliable and only 2-4 times as expensive as the MLC ones!

Comment: How do I find out which one of my USB sticks is a SLC and not a MLC? (I have so many)

Comment: I never paid attention 2 prices, most are 64gb +/- each.Thank you for the note on accepting the answer as I never did that before and probably made some people mad.

Comment: 64GB is about 100 USD for an SLC.  (they use the same technology expensive SSD hard drives use) And you can still go out and accept the old answers now...  (It'll make your reputation go up)